# Is there a nightly build for BETA_JAVA7 branch of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, download, java-7, nightly-build

I want start with the Java 7 development. But the current Eclipse IDE does not support Java 7. There is a BETA_JAVA7 branch. Is there a nightly build available? Or is the only solution to compile the branch self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet. However, an update site should become available soon (we are working on it).

Edit: The update site is now available, see http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-7-support-in-eclipse-jdt-beta.html

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't know about any nightly build of this branch. The wiki page http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java7 does not list any related information, and no such job is present in the Eclipse Hudson instance, and there is no newer information in the forum or the bugzilla (at least my search did not turn any result).